# What's exactly is moment of inertia?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, tensor-calculus, definition, moment-of-inertia

I know that angular momentum can be expressed in terms of [moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) tensor as follows,
$$\vec{L}= I_{\text{tensor}}\vec{w}$$
Where $I_{\text{tensor}}$ is tensor for moment of inertia. It can be derived easily from expression for angular momentum combined with $\vec{v}=\vec{r}×\vec{w}$. Followed by scalar triple product.

Now I see that my textbook mentions the definition of moment of inertia as
$$I=\sum_{k\leq n} m_{k}r^{2}_{k}$$

Now, i see that it's similar to one of my coordinates in the inertia tensor. But I am not sure how to understand this version of definition.

My question is how to get this definition from tensor definition of it.

Answer (score 0):

The moment of inertia describes an objects tendency to remain rotating. We can think of it on similar terms to mass for momentum, where mass gives an object a greater tendency to continue its motion.

For a point mass rotating about some axis at distance $r$, we have that $I = mr^2$

Now if we extend this concept to be the moment of inertia for a system of three point masses, at distances $r_1, r_2, r_3$ from the rotation axis, we sum the moments for each mass as: $$I = \sum_k{m_kr_k^2} = m_1r_1^2+m_2r_2^2+m_3r_3^2$$

The above is the definition you are seeing in your text. Now we can apply this concept in a more useful form, where we are summing up individual point masses within a continuous mass distribution. We write: $$I = \int r^2dm$$

where our limits of integration are across the whole continuous mass.

As you stated, we can write $\vec{L}$ in tensor form: $$\vec{L} = \tilde{I}\vec{\omega} \space\space\space \rightarrow \space\space\space \begin{bmatrix}L_x\\L_y\\L_z \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}I_{xx} & I_{xy}&I_{xz}\\I_{yx}&I_{yy}&I_{yz}\\I_{zx}&I_{zy}&I_{zz}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\omega_x\\\omega_y\\\omega_z\end{bmatrix}$$

Where $\tilde{I}$ represents the moment of inertia tensor matrix above. We can write each $I$ from their definitions ($I_{xx}$ and $I_{xy}$ as examples): $$I_{xx} = \sum_k(y_k^2+z_k^2)m_k = \int(y^2+z^2)dm$$

$$I_{xy} = I_{yx} = -\sum_kx_ky_km_k = -\int{xy\space dm}$$

Comment: apologies. But i still don't see how are $$\int_{}^{}r^{2}\mathrm{dm}$$ is related with $I_{xx}$ or $I_{xy}$ or $I_{xz}$...?

Comment: Use the sum definition to create the integral. You are summing every infinitesimal mass at each distance squared, so you can integrate if given information about the object you're calculating the moment for. If you calculate each $I$ within the tensor matrix, you can extract the $\vec{L}$.

Comment: yes I do agree. But my goal was not to calculate the angular momentum but to understand the relationship between  $$I=\sum_{k\leq n}m_{k}r^{2}_{k}$$ and the tensor definition. In other words why are the entries of tensor matrix related to the formula given in my text?

Comment: To use the tensor form, you need all entries of the tensor matrix. Each $I$ within the moment tensor is solvable using the formula given in your text, which is more conveniently written as an integral for continuous masses. $I_{xx}, I_{yy}, I_{zz}$ are simply the moments of inertia about the x, y and z axes respectively

Comment: The formula for the tensor is for the moment of inertial about a *point,* and is useful for the general motion of rigid bodies. The second is the moment of inertial about a *fixed axis,* and is ony useful  when the axis is  indeed held fixed.